# React native can't scroll when using TouchableWithoutFeedback to dismiss keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the follow code to dismiss my keyboard when I click outside of the text box. It works however I have different issue where I can't scroll my flatlist components. I also have issue with my scrollview no longer working. how can I fix this

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} 
                          accessible={false}>
     <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
         ...Rest of the Application Code...
     </ScrollView>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on https://reactnative.dev/docs/view you can wrap your ScrollView inside `<View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>`

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback 
 onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} 
 accessible={false}
>
 <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
     <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
         ...Rest of the Application Code...
     </ScrollView>
 </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: Worked once then it stop working for some reason

Comment: strange this should work always r u using "TouchableWithoutFeedback" from "react-native-gesture-handler" ?, or try it without "accessible" prop

Comment: I get this warning: Sending `onAnimatedValueUpdate` with no listeners registered.

Comment: there is no aimated value used here i think problem is somewhere else try adding this into your App.js and if it works it means you have problem somewhere else

Comment: If I remove the TouchableWithoutFeedback wrapper it works except there is no way for me to disable all inputsText when I click away

Comment: You can also use ScrollView with ```keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'``` to only dismiss the keyboard when the tap is not handled by the children

Comment: Should this be a wrapper that goes outside <NavigationContainer></NavigationContainer> or should it go inside of the navigation container